# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rviz/rviz]: rviz

Tags: robotic-arm, rviz, ros-groovy, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while I launching files in my ros groovy I have got this error message

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rviz/rviz]: rviz
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/unais/x_warm/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

could you know what may be the issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108736/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Brviz/rviz%5D:-rviz/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz is not uspported for ubuntu groovy on arm plateform.

See the Ubuntu ARM build farm status:
namniart.com/repos/status/groovy.html

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1